# I have to clear cookies each time I modify css file

Tags: css, cookies, web, less

This is such an annoying and timeconsuming bug!

Since a while back I have to clear the cookies each time I change something in my .css file. Well, currently it's a .less file. But this has happened to me before and also my buddy when working with a .css file.

If I don't clear cookies after a change nothing happens with the site..

Frustrating!

Someone have any good explanation for this strange behavior? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Are you sure your CSS isn't just getting cached by the browser? The next time you modify your CSS file try performing a hard refresh (generally CTRL+F5 on Windows, CMD+SHIFT+R on Mac).

Comment: Alternatively adding a version number at the end, and changing that number every time you edit would have the same effect

Comment: That works, I can CMD+SHIFT+R every time I want to refresh instead. But it still doesn't work with just CMD+R. Thanks

Comment: CMD+R will not work as your browser will render the page using the (old) cached CSS file. A hard refresh (CMD+SHIFT+R) will bypass any cached files and display the web page as it currently appears on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that cookies affect your styling but if you have issue with cached css file try adding timestamp to your css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/your/path/to/cssfile.css?{Add a timestamp here}" />
```

also you can use a bookmarklet(it actually adds timestamp for you):

```
javascript:void(function(){var i,a,s;a=document.getElementsByTagName('link');for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){s=a[i];if(s.rel.toLowerCase().indexOf('stylesheet')>=0&&s.href) {var h=s.href.replace(/(&|%5C?)forceReload=\d+/,'');s.href=h+(h.indexOf('?')>=0?'&':'?')+'forceReload='+(new Date().valueOf())}}})();
```