# Can't get sticky navbar to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

First, why isn't http://jsfiddle.net/s4eMT/ working?

Second, the js-code that I put in jsfiddle is working in my project but I have a some kind of browser-support issue.

When I run the website in Chrome it works as expected, it gets fixed when you scroll down to the navbar, when I run it in Safari and Firefox it sets the navbar fixed but also shrinks the navbar way smaller and floating left. I can't figure out what it is that's not supported by the last mentioned browsers.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div id="navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbar-inner hidden-phone">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li @if(page=="services"){class="active"}><a href="/services">@Messages("NavServices")</a></li>
                    <li @if(page=="work"){class="active"}><a href="/work">@Messages("NavWork")</a></li>
                    <li class="logo hidden-phone"><a href="/"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/HF_logo_inverted.png")" class="img-circle" alt="Home" /></a></li>
                    <li @if(page=="wall"){class="active"}><a href="/wall">@Messages("NavWall")</a></li>
                    <li @if(page=="contact"){class="active"}><a href="/contact">@Messages("NavContact")</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-inner visible-phone">
                <ul class="nav phone-only">
                    <li @if(page=="services"){class="active"}><a href="/services">@Messages("NavServices")</a></li>
                    <li @if(page=="work"){class="active"}><a href="/work">@Messages("NavWork")</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav phone-only">
                    <li @if(page=="wall"){class="active"}><a href="/wall">@Messages("NavWall")</a></li>
                    <li @if(page=="contact"){class="active"}><a href="/contact">@Messages("NavContact")</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
           <div id="language" class="hidden-phone">
                <a href="@if(page!="index"){/@page}else{/}"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/gb.png")" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a href="#"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/se.png")" /></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#navbar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 100%;
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  var stickyNavTop = $('#navbar-wrapper').offset().top;

  var stickyNav = function () {
      var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scrollTop > stickyNavTop) {
          $('#navbar-wrapper').css({
              'position': 'fixed',
                  'top': '0'
          });
          alert('afa');
      } else {
          $('#navbar-wrapper').css({
              'position': 'relative'
          });
      }
  };

  stickyNav();

  $(window).scroll(function () {
      stickyNav();
  });
});
```

What am I missing?

regards,

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working because you haven't included jQuery. Fix that and it works for me in both Chrome and Firefox. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcybR/)

Comment: Include Jquery to get it work.

Comment: My mistake. Will do. You have any suggestions for the main issue? Why it won't work in Safari and Firefox, but Chrome does the work?

Comment: It does work in jsFiddle on both firefox and safari. Maybe it's something that interferes with the nav. But it is working on Chrome :(

Comment: If the jsFiddle is working, it's hard for us to spot the problem. Maybe you could provide more of the code?

Comment: I'm not sure what more to show, that's what's included for this navbar.. Damn

Comment: Bah, found the problem. Such an annoying issue. I had to do a hard-refresh in all browsers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17876633/i-have-to-clear-cookies-each-time-i-modify-css-file